# .NETCore Oracle ManagedDataAccess Client: cannot read BLOBs (TTC error)

Tags: oracle, .net-core, blob

I have .NET Core app and we are trying to use Oracle Managed Data Access Client (currently it has beta version only).

However, when I read BLOB from database it gets 'TTC Error'. Does anyone have any ideas how to proceed?

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=db;User ID=userid;Password=pass;Pooling=False;"))
{
    conn.Open();
    var sql = "SELECT id, blobdata FROM templ";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    using (reader)
    {
         while (reader.Read()) //TTC Error
         {
         }
    }
```

"TTC Errror" is main Exception message.

Comment: Your best option is to provide [feedback](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/windows_and_.net/odp.net) to Oracle on issue.

Comment: You could also try an alternative library [MySqlConnector](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/).

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4334094/is-any-plan-to-fixed-the-bug-about-clob-in-oracle-10g

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal but I ran into this issue today and ended up using the DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR function to read it out in chucks of 2000 (2000 is the largest that RAW can be).

Below is a query that returns a row where each row is 2K chucks of the file at a specific offset.

```
WITH
INFO
AS
(
    SELECT
        dbms_lob.getlength(A.FILE_CONTENT) AS FILE_CONTENT_LENGTH, 
        MOD(dbms_lob.getlength(A.FILE_CONTENT),2000) AS MOD,
        CASE
            WHEN MOD(dbms_lob.getlength(A.FILE_CONTENT),2000) > 0 THEN TRUNC((dbms_lob.getlength(A.FILE_CONTENT)/2000) + 1)
            ELSE TRUNC(dbms_lob.getlength(A.FILE_CONTENT)/2000)
        END INTERATION_COUNT,
        A.FILE_CONTENT,
        A.FILE_ID
      FROM TABLE_OF_FILES A WHERE A.FILE_ID = 345321561
)
,OFFSETS AS
(
    SELECT
        (2000 * (ROWNUM-1)) + 1 AS OFFSET,
        I.MOD,
        I.FILE_CONTENT_LENGTH,
        I.FILE_CONTENT,
        I.FILE_ID,
        I.INTERATION_COUNT
    FROM INFO I
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= I.INTERATION_COUNT
)
,RESULT AS
(
    SELECT
        DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(O.FILE_CONTENT, 2000, O.OFFSET) AS CONTENT,
        O.OFFSET,
        O.MOD,
        O.FILE_CONTENT_LENGTH,
        O.FILE_ID,
        O.INTERATION_COUNT
    FROM OFFSETS O
)
SELECT * FROM RESULT R ORDER BY R.OFFSET ASC;
```